# Import Android project using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, projects-and-solutions

I'm having trouble trying to import a project. After doing so I get 6 error items. Of which 4 are the same (`Unable to resolve target 'Android-8'`).

Another one is: `Project 'MyProject' is missing required Java project: 'org.json'`.
Even though the file `org.json.jar` is in the libs folder.

And the last one is: `The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved`.

What can I do to make Eclipse properly import my projects?

I even tries to create a new project and manually copie the files, but didn't turn out as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]To import the existing project

```
Project Explorer-->new Android Project from Existing Resource-->select project and check copy to the work space option(if you need)--> finish.
```

1. Problem

   Unable to resolve target 'Android-8'

   Right click on the project-->android-->select the target as 8 and save.
2. org.json.jar

Download this jar from the internet and paste the jar file in the lib folder.

3.Clean the projec once

Comment: I don't have the option Android when I right click my project under `Package Explorer`

Comment: And also don't have `new Android Project from Existing Resource`.

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to resolve target 'Android-8'

You dont have Android-8 SDK installed on your pc.Concider downloading this SDK or if you have any SDK above this version just select it. under project properties.

> Project 'MyProject' is missing required Java project: 'org.json'

This message suggest you that this project is expecting `org.json` library project in your workspace and you should include it as library project.
If you have got jar file then its fine,under project properties just remove library project dependancies and include jar file in build path.

Answer (score 0):

How have you installed the ADT? 
It's possible that if Android options aren't available, you haven't installed the ADT plugin correctly.

I would do the following:

1. Ensure that the ADT is installed
2. Delete the project and re-import it under the option "Import existing Android code into workspace"
3. Check that the build path options are correct. Android projects add jars in the lib folder to projects automatically, but this is worth checking.

Keep us posted!